# ngx-translate-router Angular Universal SSR : NetworkError at XMLHttpRequest.send

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I am implementing ngx-translate-router in an Angular Universal app that is already working in SSR but once I added this module SSR does not run anymore.
But works correctly with `ng serve` so it means that the integration of this module without SSR is working fine.

But when running in SSR mode : `npm run serve:ssr` i get this error :

```
NetworkError
at XMLHttpRequest.send (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:819512)
at Observable_Observable._subscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:3285565)
at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:576303)
at Observable_Observable.subscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:576085)
at CatchOperator.call (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:3994238)
at Observable_Observable.subscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:575939)
at DoOperator.call (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:3343772)
at Observable_Observable.subscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:575939)
at F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:3315893
at Observable_Observable._subscribe (F:\GitaLab\vyv-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:3316238)
```

I implemented the SSR part based on the instructions of [ngx-translate-router](https://github.com/gilsdav/ngx-translate-router#initialize-module) so what i did additional for the SSR part are the following :

1 - implemented an interceptor in the app.server.module.ts to be able to access the translations within the server part. Here is the interceptor :

```js
    import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
    import * as express from 'express';
    import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class TranslateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      private readonly DEFAULT_PORT = 4200;
      private readonly PORT = process.env.PORT || this.DEFAULT_PORT;
    
      constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: express.Request) {}
    
      getBaseUrl(req: express.Request) {
        const { protocol, hostname } = req;
        return this.PORT ?
          `${protocol}://${hostname}:${this.PORT}` :
          `${protocol}://${hostname}`;
      }
    
      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (request.url.startsWith('./assets')) {
          const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl(this.request);
          request = request.clone({
            url: `${baseUrl}/${request.url.replace('./assets', 'assets')}`
          });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }
```

2 - I modified the server.ts to access the different locales and added the routes for them, but I think the issues lies there. I think I incorrectly added the routes listening in the server.ts but i did not find help about this anywhere...

here is the server.ts

```js
// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const data: any = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`src/assets/locales.json`, 'utf8'));
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  server.use(cookieParser());
  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);
  server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const defaultLang = 'en';
    const lang = req.acceptsLanguages('en', 'de', 'fr', 'es', 'pt');
    let cookieLang = req.cookies.lang;
    if (!cookieLang) {
      cookieLang = req.cookies.LOCALIZE_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE; // This is the default name of cookie
    }
    const definedLang = cookieLang || lang || defaultLang;
    console.log('domain requested without language');
    res.redirect(301, `/${definedLang}/`);
  });
  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
  console.log('routes for the locales:');
  console.log(data);
  data.locales.forEach(route => {
    server.get(`/${route}`, (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
      console.log('domain requested with language' + req.originalUrl);
      res.render(indexHtml, {
        req, providers: [
          { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
        ]
      });
    });
    server.get(`/${route}/*`, (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
      console.log('page requested with language ' + req.originalUrl);
      res.render(indexHtml, {
        req, providers: [
          { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
        ]
      });
    });
  });
  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.use(compression());
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

when I start the SSR server and then request the page http://localhost
I can see the redirect working to the default language and the console logs the `"domain requested with language /en/"` before the error reported above.

I think the issue is that the server.ts does not manage to map the requested url to something within the routes declared in the app-routing.module.ts but i don't know how to do that.
In the GitHub repository of ngx-translate-router they say :

```js
// let node server knows about the new routes:

let fs = require('fs');
let data: any = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`src/assets/locales.json`, 'utf8'));
 
app.get('/', ngApp);
data.locales.forEach(route => {
  app.get(`/${route}`, ngApp);
  app.get(`/${route}/*`, ngApp);
});
```

but they don't describe what "ngApp" is so i just extrapolated it base on how the server.ts was before integrating this plugin:

```
  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req, providers: [
        { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
      ]
    });
  });
```

So my question is double. Do you think I am right to keep searching on the direction that I dentified ? (server.ts implementation is wrong).
If yes do you have an idea how to correct it ?
If no, any other direction to look for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not in the server.ts, but the interceptor. I originally designed this interceptor and I thought it could be shared just like that to retrieve the data from ./assets/locales.json as it was working fine in SSR for retrieving the ./assets/i18n/en.json, but no luck. ngx-translate and ngx-translate-router cannot share the same interceptor, I don't know why but that's it. So I had to create a second interceptor (code below) and this solved my issue.

```js
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import * as express from 'express';
import {Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class LocalizeInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: express.Request, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (request.url.startsWith('assets') && isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      const req = this.request;
      const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/' + request.url;
      request = request.clone({
        url
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```